# how to set parameters to server from android application?

Tags: java, android, http, request, response

I have the following code to connect from my android application to zappos api server and search for some stuff. But It either returns `error 404 or We are unable to process the request from the input feilds given`.

When I execute the same query it works on the web browser.

## The query is:

`http://api.zappos.com/Search&term=boots&key=<my_key_inserted_here>`

## Code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://api.zappos.com/Search");

NameValuePair keypair = new BasicNameValuePair("key",KEY);
NameValuePair termpair = new BasicNameValuePair("term",data);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

params.add(keypair);
params.add(termpair);

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

String str;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(entity.getContent());
    while (( str = in.readLine()) != null){
        sb.append(str);
    }

    in.close();
}

Log.i("serverInterface","response from server is :"+sb.toString());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would begin by looking through the docs for Commons-HttpClient and figure out a way to make sure the request that is actually being made is what you're expecting.

Comment: 1. Are You sending a `POST` request when API server expects `GET`?
2. Maybe the API server expects the client to set `Accept: application/json` header or some other headers?

Comment: if it helps, the documentation page at http://developer.zappos.com/ says it is a REST api. I don't know what that means. Can you explain what it is? I don't think GET works either

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, what you want to do is a GET request with parameters.

Then,the code would looks like something like that:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://api.zappos.com/Search");

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter("key", "KEY");
    params.setParameter("term", "data");
    get.setParams(params);

    HttpResponse response;
    response = client.execute(get);

    String str;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        DataInputStream in;
        in = new DataInputStream(entity.getContent());
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(str);
        }
        in.close();
    }

    Log.i("serverInterface", "response from server is :" + sb.toString());
```

Comment: Hi No luck. The message as shown in the response from the server is : access is denied. Status Code 403

Comment: It's also what I get when I test the url you provided : http://api.zappos.com/Search&term=boots&key=<my_key_inserted_here>
Are you sure that your key is correct?

Comment: Yeah. It was generated by the recruiters at zappos. This is a common interview question. It works now. Please see the answer I posted. And thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the question based on ALL of your help. I got the hint that I must search how to connect to REST service and I also used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769549/how-send-http-request-in-android-app-to-access-rest-api) result. This is the exact result I was looking for. Sadly it resembles too much to what I'm trying to achieve that I think whoever asked it might be applying to the same position :(