# Get username based on user ID using REST api in android studio

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, yii

I am newbie in native android development. I am working on `android studio`. I have created a `web service api` using `yii`, also i have created two tables in `mysql` named `Users` and `Activity`, Entered some data into the `User` table like below

[image]

Now i want is whenever user enters the `id` of the user then the specific `username` should be shown.

For this i followed this stack [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5769576/6854117) and made layout

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName|number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/etId"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText" />

<Button
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/btn_Submit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etId" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etId"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I want to show the name on the text.

As per the link i followed it but unable to view my required result.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String URL = "http://localhost:8000/app/web/users/";
String result = "";
```

TextView tv;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etId);

    /*editText.setOnClickListener(new EditText.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(" ");
        }
    });
    */
    final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);

    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String query = editText.getText().toString();
            callWebService(query);
        }
    });

}

private void callWebService(String q) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL + q);

    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    try
    {
        result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Toast.makeText(LOG_TAG, "Hi", result).show();
    //tv.append("Hi ", result, ":" );
}
```

**Update 1**

Below is the error which i get when i tap the button

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                              at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
                                                                              at com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And it comes at point

` button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String query = editText.getText().toString();
            callWebService(query);
        }
    });`
```

**Update 2**

By following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093650/6854117) i have done the following

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Now my app won't crash but it just show me `HI` and not the requested data

While debugging it i got exception 
`org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8000 refused`

While when i request it on my browser it does show me the required result as show in below image

[image]

**NOTE:**

I am testing it on emulator.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error are u getting ?

Comment: Does your yii based API work as expected?

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez kindly see my `update 1`

Comment: @Shadow yes i have tested it on `ARC` and the `GET` method is working fine. For now i just want to use `GET` method.

Comment: try the url as hardcoded first. maybe there is something you are misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs only when you are using web operation on main thread.Run your code in `AsyncTask` or in other `Thread`:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Do network action in this function
  }
}).start();
```

Check this out for more on [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/5996106).

*NOTE*-

In simple words,

DO NOT DO NETWORK WORK IN THE UI THREAD

*But*

If you use simple thread ,When you get something from Network response and want to show it on your view (like display response message in TextView), you need to return back to the UI thread.

If you don't do it, you will get `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

So , for newbie i would suggest `AssyncTask` .

**UPDATE**

> `http://localhost`

The above host is already occupied by the ***emulator*** in which you are running the code. If you want to access the local host of your computer then use the IP Address as `http://yourip:8080/.`

For more details, please refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Comment: Not working my app stuck when i tap on `submit button`

Comment: While in `logcat` i am getting warnings for `Suspending all threads`
and `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://My_ip:8000 refused`

Comment: I have posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088579/progress-dialog-keeps-on-displaying-in-android-studio) please see it

Comment: You already have an answer there to your new question. put a check for buffer if it comes null. And, in future keep in mind Do Network work in background Task.

Answer (score 0):

you should:

1. Apply Internet permission on Manifest.xml
2. Network should not run on Main thread.you should do it on other thread
3. you can choose third party lib to simplify network request,like Volley or Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Android usually doesnot support `localhost` as the url since most computers are connected through wifi or other network. try to replace `localhost` with the `IPADDRESS` of your system. Like:

```
String URL = "http://192.168.1.1:8000/app/web/users/"; //replace 192.168.1.1 with your ip address
```

Comment: Not working my app stuck when i tap on `submit button`